# Does Multistage docker image size depend on earlier stages?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-multi-stage-build

I am building a docker image with 2 approaches:

**Approach 1.** stage 1 creates a tar of a package after building from source. In stage 2, this tar is copied and extracted folder is used for starting service.

*Image size created with approach: 1GB*

**Approach 2.** stage 1 just copies a prebuilt tar of same package(**folder size is same as approach 1 after untar**) from build context and places it in /tmp, stage 2 copies this from /tmp and extracts and follows same steps as above approach.

*Image size created with approach: 500MB*

Note: Stage 2 is exactly same in both approaches, as per my understanding whatever is being done in stage 1 should not affect the final image size.

Could someone please help on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM image:base as base
RUN create >file.tar

FROM image:release
COPY --from=base file.tar file.tar
RUN tar -xvf file.tar
RUN rm file.tar
```

The released image layers will contain the `file.tar` from the `COPY --from=base file.tar file.tar` step. Deleting the `file.tar` in a later step has no impact on that earlier layer. Any time you delete files in one step that were created in an earlier step, realize those files are still shipped with the image and accessible to anyone that inspects the image layers, they just aren't show to the process inside the container viewing the assembled layers.

Comment: So that is about stage2.. Will `RUN create >file.tar` have any effect on final image size that is generated?

Comment: @NamrataB It's the prerequisite of the later copy command, so it does have an affect. But a second step in the base stage running `RUN create >another-file.tar` would not have any affect on the second stage.